# Behavior of ThreadPoolExecutor with keepAliveTime = 0 and corePoolSize = 0

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, thread-safety, threadpool

Does setting `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s `keepAliveTime` and `corePoolSize` to `0` make it create a new `Thread` for every task? Is it guaranteed no `Thread` will ever be reused for any task?

BTW I want to set the `maximumPoolSize` to `100` or so. I cannot afford unlimited amount of threads. In case I reached the limit of the threads (e.g. 100), I want the server to fallback to 'sychronous' mode (no parallelism). See the `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`.

---

**Background** (read only in case you are interested in my motivation):

We have a project which relies on usage of `ThreadLocals` (e.g. we use Spring and its `SecurityContextHolder`). We would like to make 10 calls to backend systems in parallel. We like the `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`, which runs the callable in the caller thread in case thread pool and its task queue is full. That's why we would like to use `ThreadPoolExecutor`. I am not able to change the project not to use `ThreadLocals`, please do not suggest doing so.

I was thinking how to do it with the least amount of work. `SecurityContextHolder` can be switched to use `InheritableThreadLocal` instead of `ThreadLocal`. The thread-local variables are then passed to child threads when the child threads are created. The only problem is how to make `ThreadPoolExecutor` create new `Thread` for every task. Will setting its `keepAliveTime` and `corePoolSize` to `0` work? Am I sure none of the threads will be reused for a next task? I can live with performance hit of creating new `Threads`, because the parallel tasks take much more time each.

Other possible solutions considered:

1. Extend `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s `execute` method and wrap the `Runnable command` parameter into a different `Runnable` which remembers thread-locals into its final fields and then initializes them in its `run` method before calling the target `command`. I think this might work, but it is sligtly more code to maintain than the solution my original question is about.
2. Pass thread-locals in a parameter of asynchronous methods. This is more verbose to use. Also people can forget to do it, and the security context would be shared between asynchronous tasks :-(
3. Extend `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s `beforeExecute` and `afterExecute` methods and copy thread-locals using reflection. This requires ~50 lines of ugly reflection code and I am not sure how safe it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, this does not work! `ThreadPoolExecutor` wraps your `Callable`/`Runnable` into an internal `Worker` object and executes it in its [`runWorker()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java?av=f#1120) method. The Javadoc of this method says:

> Main worker run loop.  Repeatedly gets tasks from queue and executes them, while coping with a number of issues: ...

You can also take a look at the code of this method and see that it does not exit until the task queue is empty (or something bad happens which causes the thread to exit).

So setting `keepAliveTime` to 0 will not necessarily cause a new thread on each submitted task.

You should probably go with your solution 3 as the `beforeExecute()` and `afterExecute()` methods are exactly meant for dealing with ThreadLocals.

Alternatively, if you insist of having new threads for each task, you may take a look at Spring's [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html). It guarantees you a new thread for each task and allows you to set a concurrency limit, i.e. the equivalent of `ThreadPoolExecutor#maxPoolSize`.

Comment: So, it will work - provided the task queue is empty.

Comment: Thank you. I took a look into the `ThreadPoolExecutor` code and I agree with you. It is not _guaranteed_ that no thread will be reused. I'm actually going for alternative solution 1, because I know precisely which thread-locals I want to copy. I tested it, it works. And it is more readable than the 3rd alternative solution (althought it would probably work too). `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` will not work for me because it doesn't have the `CallerRunsPolicy` available for it, which I would like to use.